# The file tal.java already exists

Tags: java, netbeans, ubuntu

estoy usando Netbeans, y después de cambiar los templates para que @autor pusiera mi nombre, cada vez que intento crear una clase me pasa lo siquiente:
Pongo el nombre (cualquiera, incluso teclas al azar); en cuanto pulso Finish aparece una clase vacía en ese paquete y el mensaje "The file tal.java already exists." 
He desinstalado el programa en ubuntu, con Synaptic, luego "Sudo apt-get update" y "sudo apt-get autoremove" y sudo "apt-get autoclean".
Después lo he vuelto a instalar con "Sudo apt-get install netbeans" y repito todo lo anterior. Pero al lanzar el programa me sale el mismo autor que metí (en alguna parte se tiene que quedar reflejado cuando lo borro) y tengo el mismo problema. Uso Ubuntu desde hace poco, y no estoy muy ducho en este programa. Les agradecería una indicación para resolver este problema; por internet he buscado mucho y no encuentro solución.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que importa no es borrar el programa, sino borrar la configuración del programa, que lo más seguro es que esté en tu carpeta `/home`. Prueba con:

`locate netbeans.conf`

o con:

`find ./ -name 'netbeans.conf'`

para buscar la carpeta donde se encuentra la configuración y prueba primero a renombrar dicha carpeta. Cuando te hayas asegurado de que Netbeans está funcionando correctamente, borra la carpeta que renombraste.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Lo he buscado como me has indicado y lo he encontrado en el archivo "etc". Después de escribir la consulta, volví a entrar en "templates" y puse todos los @author en user, que es como estaban, y el programa volvió a funcionar. Ahora voy a volver a personalizarlo, y cuando me falle borraré el archivo de configuración como me has indicado. Muchas gracias.